# Запуск окна на PyQt5 из Tkinter

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, tkinter, процесс

Есть Desktop приложение на `tkinter`, делаю окно для открытия и просмотра email.
В `tkinter` только html получается просмотреть, а письмо в том виде в котором оно приходит приходится отправлять в браузер.
Я хочу открывать и смотреть почту в своем окне. Решил использовать для этого `QWebEngineView` из `PyQt5`, который запускаю из `tkinter`.
Проблема: Первый раз запускается и отрабатывает как нужно, при повторном запуске, программа полностью вылетает. Пробовал запускать через `Thread` в отдельном потоке, но результат тот же. Пробовал переименовывать поток, используя `random` - тоже не помогло.
Выход вижу либо переписывать заново всю прогу на `PyQt5`, либо сделать отдельное приложение на `PyQt` и запускать отдельно, но задумка теряется.
Что почитать или в каком направлении идти что бы скрестить все-таки их?

Добавил пример с минимальным кодом при котором воспроизводится проблема

```
import tkinter as tk
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()

def init_main(self):
    self.label = tk.Label(self, text='После первого нажатия на кнопку все отрабатывает,\n'
                                     ' потом закрываем окно \n'
                                     'и повторно жмем кнопку и программа рушится\n')
    self.label.pack(side=tk.TOP)
    self.btn = tk.Button(self, text='Нажми меня', command=self.open_read_mail)
    self.btn.pack(side=tk.TOP)

def open_read_mail(self):
    # self.filepath = 'https://www.example.com'  # 'file:///__Страшно_горят_цены_в_21vek___/index.html'
    # web_text = self.filepath
    web = Web()   # web_text
    web.open()


class Web:
    def __init__(self, url='https://www.example.com', title='Входящее сообщение'):
        self.title = title
        self.url = url

def init_child(self):

    self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.centralwidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 50, 700, 600))

    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 10, 600, 20))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

    self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 40, 600, 20))
    self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

    self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
    self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 70, 600, 371))
    self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
    self.frame.setObjectName("frame")

    self.web = QWebEngineView(self.frame)
    self.web.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.web.load(QUrl(self.url))
    self.web.resize(600, 550)

    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 21, 16))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")

    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 31, 16))
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

    self.label.setText("От:")
    self.label_2.setText("Тема:")

    qbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Quit', self.centralwidget)
    qbtn.clicked.connect(self.close_window)
    qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
    qbtn.move(1, 60)

def close_window(self):
    self.centralwidget.close()
    #sys.exit(0)

def open(self):
    self.init_child()
    self.centralwidget.show()
    self.app.exec()
    #sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.geometry("400x200+100+100")
    root.resizable(True, True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: всякое бывает, конечно, но почему бы не использовать только qt, раз вы уже его используете?

Comment: @0dminnimda . Только начал учить Python решил сделать для своих нужд десктоп приложение, написал уже 2400 срок кода и думаю успешно справился с остальным но наткнулся на то что ткинтер не справляется с одной нужно функцией, хотелось бы найти решение и закончить свой проект. В дальнейшем попробую сделать что-то и на PyQt5 и на джанго и других фреймворках. Пока пытаюсь решить всетаки этот вопрос, думаю решение есть просто я в силу своей неопытности не понимаю в каком направлении решение.

Comment: Если уж хотите продолжить с двумя, то вам стоит предоставить [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), при котором сохраняется неверное поведение; но мне кажется, что можно самостоятельно обрабатывать взаимодействие с почтой, тем более уже есть библиотеки для этого, например встроенные библиотеки [email](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) + [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) или другие библиотеки из pypi, выбрать есть из чего.

Comment: Добавил код из-за которого я ломаю голову сейчас)

Comment: Как я понимаю проблема не в том что бы просмотреть в отдельном окне содержимое письма а в том что бы закрыть это окно правильно, что бы  когда я запускаю просмотр второго письма все отрабатывала так же корректно. Но когда я завершаю окно на Pyqt5 или вылетает вся программа а не только отдельное окно или закрывается только окно но при перезапуске рушится приложение это зависит от разницы способов закрыть окно, но результат всегда один...)

Comment: Если я запускаю только один раз то все ок, можно закрыть окно и работать дальше в приложении все работает, но если повторно попробовать считать второе письмо в списке то тогда все программа рушится

Comment: Повторюсь, приведите [mre]. Прочитайте всю статью и последуйте изложенным советам. Про "код из обработки чтения письма". Он совершенно вырван из контекста, потому он не помогает понять проблему, а только добавляет вопросы. Также с отступами большая беда (когда вставляете код, проследите за тем, чтобы все отступы сохранялись и имели смысл в данном контексте).

Comment: К слову, почему так важно привести [mre]. Попытайтесь воспроизвести вашу проблему, пользуясь только предоставленным вами в вопросе кодом, не дописывая ничего существенного. Если у вас получится, то опубликуйте именно этот код.

Comment: Добавил код при котором возникает ошибка, только думаю тут не в коде дело а в завершении процесса pyqt и совместной работе tk и pyqt. Думаю если правильно завершить процесс нового окна то все будет работать дальше